# Skin Flex 4 combobox to look like Flex 3 combobox

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, skinning, halo

As I have migrated my application to Flex 4 recently, I want to utilize the `<s:Combobox>` component in my application rather than `<mx:Combobox>`. The problem is that the look and feel of both are different.

How can I make the `<s:Combobox />` component look (all skinning e.g. hover over, click, outline) exactly the same as `<mx:Combobox />`?

More specifically, I want to apply the Halo theme to a DropdownList component. Is that possible?

Comment: In general, I want to know how we can make any flex 4 component look like as if it was a flex 3(spark) component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just set the default skin for your application to Hero instead of Spark. Assuming you're using Flash Builder:

1. Click on *Project* -> *Properties*.
2. Click *Flex Theme* from the properties list.
3. Expand *Adobe Themes - Halo* and select the Halo theme.

Comment: It is already selected. Also, I use ant task to compile swf where I have added this line and using flex.theme property in mxmlc task,                                                     `<property name="flex.theme" value="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/themes/Halo/halo.swc"/>`

Comment: If you are using the Halo theme it should look nearly identical - and, this is the only broad brush approach to do what you're looking for.  Can you explain or post images of the differences you're trying to target?

Comment: Problem I am seeing is that Combobox is used in a custom component which internally uses spark.components.DropdownList, hence it is not picking Halo theme, it just continues displaying it in Spark theme.

Comment: Sorry, spark skinning and mx skinning are completely different.  There isn't a silver bullet for this one, you'll need to define a skin for the spark control to mimic the look and feel you want.