# Halo theme on a Spark component

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark, halo

I have a Flex form made up mostly of MX components. Due to limitations with the MX `mx.controls.ComboBox`, I'd like to use the Spark control, `spark.components.ComboBox`. This works, except the Spark ComboBox sticks out visually because it doesn't use the Halo theme.

Is there a way to have the Spark ComboBox use the Halo theme?

Comment: You can set the default theme back to Halo using the theme compiler argument; I'm not sure how it affects visuals of the Spark ComboBox, though.

Answer (score 2):

I answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6610532/275643) a while ago.

> You could just set the default skin for your application to Hero
>   instead of Spark. Assuming you're using Flash Builder:
>
> 1. Click on *Project* -> *Properties*.
> 2. Click *Flex Theme* from the properties list.
> 3. Expand *Adobe Themes - Halo* and select the Halo theme.